# Не работает filexists

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток! Не работает функция, но не совсем, а для одной директории. Может ли быть проблема в том, что в имени директории содержится нижнее подчеркивание? Если да - то что делать? Переименовывать не хотелось бы.  
ПО - php5.5/apache2.4/ubuntu12.04

Comment: > Может ли быть проблема в том, что в имени директории содержится нижнее подчеркивание

нет. Убедитесь, что вы скармливаете ей правильные имена в правильном регистре (unix к этому чувствителен)

Comment: имена и регистры правильные - из соседней директории все норм подключается

Comment: @woland
1. Нужно больше конкретики, лучше всего конкретный кусок кода с __абсолютно точно__ известными переменными.
2. То, что соседняя папка работает, не означает однозначно, что у вас все в порядке с регистрами. Я однажды с помощью панто свитчера прокосячил "с" не в том языке.
3. У пользователя есть вообще права на доступ в папку?

Comment: 1.
       
<pre>
public static function get_lang($section, $lang = 'en-EN')
    {
        static::init();

        $lang2 = [en-EN];

        $path  = '..'.DS.'lang'.DS.[simple_admin_template].DS.[admin].DS.$lang2.'.ini';
        $path2 = '..'.DS.'lang'.DS.static::$name.DS.core::$mode.DS.$lang.'.ini';

        if(file_exists($path)) {
            $ini = factory::getIniServer($path);

            return $ini->readSection($section);
        }
        /* some code*/
    }
      
</pre>
3. права есть

Comment: Какой из $path не работает? Эхали его?

    $path  = '..'.DS.'lang'.DS.[simple_admin_template].DS.[admin].DS.$lang2.'.ini';

Это, надеюсь, не массивы в строке?

Comment: оба не работают.   
выводил - все верно  выводит    
не массивы конечно - так я показал, что подставил значения переменных

Comment: если realpath($path) вернет пустую строку, то, скорее всего, $path-таки неправильный. Я подозреваю, что ошибка появляется из-за относительного пути, попробуйте использовать стандартную схему с абсолютными (входной скрипт задает корень приложения, все файлы подтягиваются как APP_ROOT.'/dir/dir2/file.php').

Comment: realpath($path) возвращает false;    
пробовал указывать путь начиная с папки /var - то же самое

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Какая-то дикая ситуация. Попробуйте пересоздать папку, сделать в терминале ls 'то, что php выведет через echo $path' (не забыв про относительность пути). Или сделать mkdir той же папки из php, посмотреть, будет ли ошибка или и вправду рядом что-то создаст (может, и вправду где-то непечатные символы забрались).